# Regular expression in impala

Tags: impala

I need to escape special character from the pattern and skip last four digits:
08_27_19-13_00_34
Output:082719
Can anyone guide me how to use regexp_extract for this in impala?
Also can anyone please suggest links of article so that I can thoroughly understand regular expression working.

Comment: Can you also include what the output would be using the input data you showed us?

Comment: Sure sir I need on to get only first six numeric digits like here output should be 082719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a combination of `REPLACE` and `LEFT` here:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(REPLACE(col, '_', ''), 6) AS first_six
FROM yourTable;
```

The strategy here is to just remove the underscores, then take the first remaining six characters, which should be first six digits.  You could also consider adding logic which checks if the `col` value would even match your pattern, but that would be up to you.